# How to add multiple spaces between characters in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

If I want 10 spaces between characters "a" and "b" I press the space bar 10 times, but when I hit "<kbd>Enter</kbd> the cell defaults to only displaying 2 spaces. When I click back to edit that cell the display shows the 10 spaces, but only when I am in the "edit" mode for that cell.  How can I get the spacing to stay at 10?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case anymore. When I enter `a          b`, it stays that way.

Comment: Maybe I'm just magic.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula.

### Formula

```
="a" & REPT(CHAR(160),10) & "b"
```

### Explained

The `CHAR(160)` will give a [non-breaking space](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/charset/iso160-191.html), that's being repeated 10 times by the `REPT` formula. The text (between quotes) is concatenated with the ampersand (`&`) to form a string.

### Screenshot

[image]